# Why does clicking on a project in the Xcode navigator show a raw pbxproj file

Tags: xcode

... rather than a gui for build phases, targets, etc?

I usually see the gui.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sometimes this happens because you are in version-control view. There are three buttons: normal view, assistant view, and version-control view. Make sure you're in one of the first two.

[image]

EDIT: Also, I had another thought. "pbxproj"??? The current suffix is "xcodeproj", and has been for a really long time. You might be just trying to open a file that's too old for your version of Xcode.

Comment: That's a fantastic point. +1 to you. It might be worth showing her a screenshot of what you mean.

Comment: OK, added screen shot showing the three buttons (though exactly what you see here depends on what version of Xcode, toolbar settings, system, etc. etc.)

Comment: If you click on the "xcodeproj" folder, it will show the source of the "pbxproj" file *in* that folder.

Answer (score 3):

Today switch editor mode button looks like on screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It *sounds* like you might have a slightly corrupted pbxproj file.

Any chance you can back out your most recent changes and see if Xcode opens the project nicely again?

When Info.plist files are corrupted, that's the behavior that Xcode follows (instead of showing the plist editor, Xcode will just open up a text editor showing the raw XML-ish-ness of a plist file).